# Cookie not being set in safari

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, safari

I have a nextjs backend acting as a proxy. It basically forwards my request to another backend, and after receiving a response it sets a http only secure cookie. Here's the code :

```
const handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    axios
        .post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE}/auth/login`, req.body)
        .then(response => {
            const expires = new Date(
                new Date().getTime() + response.data.expires_in
            );

            res.setHeader(
                "Set-Cookie",
                serialize("jwt", `${response.data.access_token}`, {
                    expires,
                    secure: true,
                    httpOnly: true,
                    sameSite: "none",
                    path: "/",
                })
            );

            res.send("succes");
        })
        .catch(err =>
            res.status(err.response.status).send({ message: err.message })
        );
};
```

It's working in Chrome and Firefox, but in safari it's not setting any cookies. I tried the `samesite:none` option

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by setting

```
secure: false,
```

Having it true does not allow you to set the cookie if the connection is not over https. Since I was testing on localhost this was an issue for me. I will set it back to true on production.

Comment: How does anyone use Safari for dev?

Comment: @TravisReeder if you're developing a Tauri app - which uses webview, you don't have a choice :)